# Failed to Launch Android Native app with Appium and JAVA

Tags: android, appium

I get the following exception when I run the Android native app on Windows 10 in Eclipse Neon with Appium server 1.3.2 (1.7.1 version):

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 23.88 seconds

Note: I am working in a proxy network. The device is detected in ADB. With the command prompt I am still facing this issue.

Comment: Post your full Appium server logs.

Comment: r u able find you device whe u run adb devices command

Comment: Yes I can able to see. Am not able to add my error code am facing issue in adding